How to add two QLabels in a vertical layout on top of a QPushButton which is in a QGridLayout, in PyQt5?
I'm trying to create a t9 Nokia on-screen keyboard with python and PYQt5, and I am coding the GUI now. The problem is I want the corresponding number and the corresponding letters to the buttons to be on different lines and font sizes. Thus, I can't just assign text to the buttons, I think?
I have tried to use QstackedWidget to stack all Widgets on top of each other, but only one widget shows when I Started the application. Then I tried multiple ways with QVBoxLayout function, but I couldn't get it to work. So I am here now because I don't know what else I can try.

If you want to show the button text on different lines, just use the new line character: button.setText('ABC\n2').

Try the rich-text button in this answer. This will allow you to use basic html for the button's text (e.g. "<span style="font-size: small">ABC</span><br><b><span style="font-size: xx-large">2</font></b>"). You will probably need to adjust the code a little to get exactly what you want. As noted there in the comments, setting the alignment of the embedded label will help; and sub-classing from QToolButton instead of QPushButton should allow better control of the size-hint.
